# Post async throw System.Net.WebException on Windows 7 WPF client

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure, ssl

Query is made from a httpclient hosted in WPF control to azure server and azure server sends the results back to WPF control. On Windows 7 Os an exception is thrown when the postasync is called. Please help me how to resolve the below exception.

Note : This works fine on Windows 10 client machine

```
    var httpContent = new StringContent(value, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var queryUri = new Uri(httpClient.BaseAddress, "content/resultvalue");
    try {
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(queryUri, httpContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var resultJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(resultJson);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //report the exception to the user
    }
```

Exception Messages: 
    WebException        : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
    IOException         : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    SocketException     : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Type         : System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message      : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Source       : System
Status       : SendFailure
Response     : 
TargetSite   : System.IO.Stream EndGetRequestStream(System.IAsyncResult, System.Net.TransportContext ByRef)
Stack Trace  :    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
        at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    Inner Exception
    ---------------
    Type         : System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    Message      : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    Source       : System
    TargetSite   : Void EndWrite(System.IAsyncResult)
    Stack Trace  :    at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        Inner Exception
        ---------------
        Type         : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        Message      : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        Source       : System
        ErrorCode    : 10054
        SocketErrorCode: ConnectionReset
        NativeErrorCode: 10054
        TargetSite   : Int32 EndReceive(System.IAsyncResult)
        Stack Trace  :    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Comment: it works fine for windows 10 client, windows 7 and windows 10 are in the same network.

Comment: i checked the securityprotocol on .net 4.7 on windows it is default. Is it possible to tell what does it mean,

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the solution, it worked like a charm for Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

It could be a firewall issue or a SecurityProtocol version mismatch.

Try this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
   SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
   SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

or as Azure TLS default version is 1.2, you could try to change it to 1.0 and see if that makes any difference (in `SSL Settings`).

Comment: the code you posted where can I added it?